# Difference between Dell monitors 3007wfp and 3008wfp

Tags: display

I have my eye on getting a 3007WFP-HC by Dell. I notice there is also a 3008WFP series available, but the price is almost double.

I can't seem to find any redeeming quality of the 3008 over the 3007, the specs seem to be identical.

Why is the 3008WFP more expensive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3008 has a scaler.  If you plan on running anything other than native resolution, that makes the 3008 a better choice.

The 3007 handles the following resolutions:

- VESA, 1280 x 800 - 50 kHz Horizontal,
  60.0 Hz Vertical
- VESA, 2560 x 1600 (digital) - 99 kHz Horizontal, 60 Hz
  Vertical

The 3008 handles the following resolutions:

- VESA, 720 x 400 – 31.47 kHz Horizontal, 70.0 Hz Vertical, 28.3 MHz
- VESA, 640 x 480 – 31.47 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 25.2 MHz
- VESA, 640 x 480 – 37.5 kHz Horizontal, 75.0 Hz Vertical, 31.5 MHz
- VESA, 800 x 600 – 37.88 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 49.5 MHz
- VESA, 800 x 600 – 46.88 kHz Horizontal, 75.0 Hz Vertical, 49.5 MHz
- VESA, 1024 x 768 – 48.36 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 65.0 MHz
- VESA, 1024 x 768 – 60.0 kHz Horizontal, 75.0 Hz Vertical, 78.75 MHz
- VESA, 1152 x 864 – 67.5 kHz Horizontal, 75.0 Hz Vertical, 108 MHz
- VESA, 1280 x 800 – 49.7 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 83.5 MHz
- VESA, 1280 x 1024 – 64.0 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 108 MHz
- VESA, 1280 x 1024 – 80.0 kHz Horizontal, 75.0 Hz Vertical, 135 MHz
- VESA, 1600 x 1200 – 75.0 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 162 MHz
- VESA, 1920 x 1200 – 74.6 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 193.5 MHz
- VESA, 2560 x 1600 – 98.71 kHz Horizontal, 60.0 Hz Vertical, 268.5 MHz

This may be a complete non-issue for you.  If you plan to hook up the monitor to your computer and never change resolutions (say, run a game), you may not care.